# How to Play all online videos

Tags: java, android, video

I store video urls in an array. I just want to play all videos in that array.

My java code is:

```
public void video_play(){

    VideoView vview= (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vview);
    vview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(prepare.txtLectureFileName[index_value]));
    vview.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    vview.requestFocus();
    vview.start();

    if(index_val>=no_of_videos){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Videos are finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        video_play();
    }
}
```

I've also tried implementing `onCompleteListener` and created a method `onCompletion()`.
But nothing worked, please help me out guys...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey try this it worked for me:

```
public void video_play(){

            VideoView vview= (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vview);
            vview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(prepare.txtLectureFileName[index_value]));
            vview.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
            vview.requestFocus();
            vview.start();
            if(index_val>=no_of_videos){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Videos are finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                 video_play();
            }
            vview.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion (MediaPlayer mp) {
                index_value++;
                video_play();
            }
        });
}
```